# Horizontal alignment doesnt work

Tags: css, alignment

Can someone tell me, how I have to define loginarea that it's centered within the blue area.

[image]

Comment: Normally this is achieved though margin: auto; but without seeing the code it's really impossible to say

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
.loginarea { margin: 0 auto; width: 300px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the loginarea text-align to center.

```
.loginarea{
text-align:center;
}
```